# Java w/ maven : getting sources from a jar file

Tags: java, jar

I write a gui app , and use image files (gif) as icons. When I run the app in my IDE - the icons appear. When I run it from a jar - they fail (null pointer exception on the resource)

The package structure is as following:

code : src/main/java/com/my/app

resources : src/main/resources/com/my/app

I wrote this little example:

```
       URL url ;

        url = GuiUtils.class.getResource("/com/my/app/gui/fading_lines_blue_64x64.gif");
        System.out.println("url: " + url);

        url = GuiUtils.class.getResource("/resources/com/my/app/gui/fading_lines_blue_64x64.gif");
        System.out.println("url: " + url);
```

When ran from the IDE:

```
url: file:/C:/Repositories/V8/trunk/MyApp/build/com/my/app/gui/fading_lines_blue_64x64.gif
url: null
```

When ran from the Jar:

```
url:null
url:jar:file:/C:/DevEnv/Projects/Viewer/testPicLoad.jar!/resources/com/cmy/app/gui/fading_lines_blue_64x64.gif
```

I solved it like this , but it's obviously not the right way to do it:

```
public static URL getResourceURL(String path) {     
        URL url = GuiUtils.class.getResource(path);
        if (url == null) {
            url = GuiUtils.class.getResource("/resources"+path);
        }
        return url;
    }
```

Suggestions?

Comment: `When ran from the Jar` what you did here?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The path sounds wrong in your second option. By default maven should put the resources into target/classes along with the compiled classes. Jaring should take all of that so thats why adding "/resources" sounds odd to me. It should be finding the gif in testPicLoad.jar!/com/cmy...

Are you doing something odd when you create the jar?

Comment: `/resources" sounds odd to me` , for me too :) @yossale how do you do can you explain

Comment: @Jigar I used eclipse to pack the jar (export..) - this seems to be the problem

Comment: @yossale: yes, I agree that that's the problem. Use Maven to build the jar. That's what it's for, after all.

Answer (score 1):

The reason it happened is because I used eclipse to pack the jar . I don't know why , but it packed it that way. When I used maven from the command line , everything worked great.

Comment: Ahh, there's your answer. Best not to use Eclipse for packing when dealing with maven projects. It doesn't understand them and doesn't understand how to pack them up and leave the test code behind etc.